# Renaming files using their content

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have several files which all start with this line:

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE **CHANGING_NAME**
> ```

I want to be able to pull the name of the procedure and use it to the rename the file. There is content to each file below this first line.

Has anyone done something like this before?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want that line to remain in the file after it's been renamed?

Comment: Is the name always the third field like that? Can the procedure name contain spaces?

Comment: I'm assuming that these are SQL stored procedures, so the names will not contain spaces and the line will need to remain in the file.

Answer (score 2):

With a lot of care and pretending that the `**CHANGING_NAME**` is well-formed:

```
for file in *.files; do mv -i -- "$file" "$(awk '{print $3; exit}' $file)" ; done
```

The -i option is to prevent accidental overriding existing files.

This version works with spaces (and many other strange characters except for /):

```
for file in *.files; do mv -i --  "$file" "$(sed -n '1s/^CREATE\ PROCEDURE\ \(.*\)$/\1/p' $file)"; done
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have all files in one directory :

```
 #!/bin/bash

 for i in *.extension :
 do

   # Assuming 3rd column of the first line is the new name of the file
   # And **CHANGING_NAME** doesn't contain any space or meta characters

   newname=$(awk 'NR==1 && /PROCEDURE/ {print $3}' "$i")
   if [ "$newname" == "" ]; then
     echo "There is no PROCEDURE in the first line";
     echo "No new name for file $i";
   else
      mv "$i" "$newname"
   fi
 done
```

Comment: You don't need head with awk. `newname=$(awk 'NR==1 && /PROCEDURE/ {print $3}' "$i")`

Answer (score 1):

You can try the next:

```
perl -lanE 'if($.==1&&/PROCEDURE/){close ARGV;say "$ARGV,$F[2]"}' files*
```

and if satisfied, change it to

```
perl -lanE 'if($.==1&&/PROCEDURE/){close ARGV;rename $ARGV,$F[2]}' files*
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I was never great with `awk` I might suggest:

```
#! /bin/bash
#

for i in *.extension
    do echo $i
    newname=$(head -1 "${i}" | cut -d ' ' -f2)
    mv -i "${i}" "${newname}"
done
```

This assumes all files you're looking for have the same extension.  If not, and you need the extension, you could use:

```
#! /bin/bash
#

for i in *
    do echo $i
    ext="${i##*.}"  
    newname=$(head -1 "${i}" | cut -d ' ' -f2)
    mv -i "${i}" "${newname}"."${ext}"
done
```

Both assume all the files are in a single directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
mv myfile `sed '1 s/.*PROCEDURE\s*//' myfile`
```

(the sed command will delete the text to the left of the word proceeding PROCEDURE regardless of how many spaces on only the first line and print it out the backticks make it execute in place so it is used as the filename to the mv command)

to move them all and add an extension .ext:

```
  ls *.ext | xargs -I {} mv {} `sed '1 s/.*PROCEDURE\s*//' {}`.ext
```

Comment: You should brief about the solution you are suggesting which could even make your answer clear!

Comment: Thanks I thought it was clear but I added an explanation anyway